# How to fetch $_FILES elements with a foreach loop?

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload multiple Images using PHP. How I can get name, size, type, `tmp_name` and error for each image using a `foreach` loop ?

The following code doesn't work well:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($_FILES['img']['name'] as $name)
    foreach ($_FILES['img']['type'] as $type)
        foreach ($_FILES['img']['size'] as $size)
            foreach ($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'] as $temp) {
/* this function check the extension of the uploaded file 
, move it from temp to specific file .. etc */
                uploadimg($i.$name, $type, $size, $temp); 
                $i++; // returns count of submitted files
            }
```

Comment: do you get at least one file or none at all?

Comment: no , i can't get any file

Comment: Lol, that code is brilliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to repeat the loop `3x3x3x3` times when let's say you have uploaded 3 files. Try something like this:

```
include 'uploadmutliphoto.php';
$size = count( $_FILES['img']['name'] );
for( $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++ ) {
    $name = $_FILES['img']['name'][$i];
    $type = $_FILES['img']['type'][$i];
    $size = $_FILES['img']['size'][$i];
    $temp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$i];
    uploadimg($i.$name, $type, $size, $temp);
}
```

Also, read about uploading multiple files [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php).

Comment: No it will actually only process 1 file with that ridiculous loop construct, that's his whole problem.